Filter query using Laravel 10 using where, whereHas, orWhere
I have created a table as follows:
Table 'adjustment' consists of columns: id, adjustment_number, status.
The adjustment table has a relationship called materialloc, and another relationship to sbin.
Then, I crafted a query program like this using Laravel 10.
$query = Adjustment::with('materialloc.sbin');
         
if ($request->has('search') && $request->input('search')) {
    $searchTerm = $request->input('search');
    $query->whereHas('materialloc.sbin', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
    });
    $query->orWhere('adjustment_number', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
}

Why doesn't the search using adjustment_number work? However, when I search by name in materialloc.sbin, it works.
Is there something wrong with my use of whereHas, where, or orWhere?

You need to merge whereHas and orWhere into a common search:
$query = Adjustment::with('materialloc.sbin');
         
if ($request->has('search') && $request->input('search')) {
    $searchTerm = $request->input('search');
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($searchTerm) {
        $q->whereHas('materialloc.sbin', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
        });
        $q->orWhere('adjustment_number', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
    });
}

Similar themed questions:

Laravel - Eloquent Has, With, WhereHas - What do they mean? - Stack Overflow answer
How to use orWhere in whereHas in Laravel - Stack Overflow answer
Use orWhere with whereHas and with in eloquent - Stack Overflow answer
Eloquent Relationships: Chaining orWhere Clauses After Relationships - Laravel Docs

In the referred Eloquent Relationships from Laravel Docs, it is well illustrated that you enclose this condition within parentheses in a common where clause. While without it (as you did), there is no parentheses, which can lead to different query behavior than expected.
